# What are two easiest numerical method to calculate $\sqrt[23]{123456789}$ by hand?

Tags: numerical-methods

What are two easiest numerical methods to calculate $\sqrt[23]{123456789}$ by hand?

I want to compare that two methods myself

Just name the methods

Comment: If such a method were *worse* than a wild guess, we wouldn't call it a method. :P

Comment: Something like Newton's method maybe?

Comment: Computing 24th power on each iteration? No, thanks

Comment: @uranix But  i saw it on TV show that someone can compute something similar in their brain.

Comment: Maybe this is one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm

Comment: For the calculation of powers use repeated squaring.

Comment: Can I bring my log tables?

Comment: @AndréNicolas No, you may not

Comment: Are you calculating the nearest integer, or are you calculating the value to an arbitrary precision, not specified ahead of time? The Guinness Book of World Records used to award the "mental calculation" record to the person who could most quickly extract the 13th-root of a 100-digit number, but the 100-digit number was guaranteed to be a perfect 13th power, which makes the problem much easier.

Comment: @MJD - it is to an arbitrary precision...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $2^{23}=8388608$ and that $10^{23}=100000000000000000000000$

Divide by $8388608$ until a value less than $8388608$ is achieved. Then multiply by $100000000000000000000000$.

Repeat as long as you want until you achieve a value close to $1$.

I discovered that $123456789 = k \times 2^{23} \times \frac 1 {10^{23}}\times 2^{23}\times 2^{23}\times 2^{23}\times \frac 1 {10^{23}}...$

$... \times 2^{23}\times 2^{23}\times 2^{23}\times \frac 1 {10^{23}}\times 2^{23}\times 2^{23}\times 2^{23}\times 2^{23}$, where $k\approx 8.53$

Since $\sqrt [23] k \approx 1$,

$\sqrt [23] {123456789} \approx 2 \times \frac 1 {10} \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times \frac 1 {10} \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times \frac 1 {10} \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2=2.048$

Comment: Interesting.  It's off by $10$ percent, though.  If you were to raise that to the $23$rd power, you'll be off by factor of $9$ (or the $8.53$ you left off the front).

Comment: If you keep endless the path suggested by Victor, I mean 0.1234567891011121314......., you will find a trascendental number (an old result of Mahler).

Comment: The value you show for $10^{23}$ is actually only $10^{10}$??

Answer (score 1):

I used to remember a calculation trick where you take $12345679$ (without the $8$), and multiply it by multiples of $9$ to get repeated digits.  That suggests that the number $123456789$ is very close to $10^{10}/81$ (as it indeed is), and therefore (since the log base $10$ of $9$ is about $0.954$) that the log of the number $123456789$ is about $10-1.908 = 8.092$.

Then divide $8.092$ by $23$: $23$ times $0.35$ is $8.05$, so you're only looking for about two thousandths on top of that: $0.352$.  If you recognize that twice that is $0.704$ and the log base $10$ of $5$ is $0.699$ (with $6$ at $0.778$), then the desired number should be about a sixteenth of the way from $\sqrt{5}$ to $\sqrt{6}$, or $2.236+0.013 = 2.249$.  Since the actual value is a bit more than $2.248$, we did all right.

Well, anyway, that's the way I would have done it mentally.

Comment: It helps to know logs of 2, 3, 5, and 7, and also their square roots.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how one would name the following, neither if it is satisfying, but $$\sqrt[23]{123456789}=\sqrt[23]{1.23456789}\cdot 10^{8/23}\approx \sqrt[23]{\sqrt{1.5}}\left(\sqrt[23]{10}\right)^8=\sqrt[46]{1.5}\cdot \left(\sqrt[23]{10}\right)^8\approx2.2472,$$ and the original root is $\approx 2.2480$. Note that the rightmost roots have more familiar radicands.

Comment: How do you know the $69$th root of $10$, or the $46$th root of $1.5$?  Do you just assume they're very close to $1$?  Or do you use logs?  Or what?

Comment: @BrianTung No, I assumed one would use some algorithm for the $n$-th root, since we ended up with nicer radicands. Though, as I said, I don't know if it is satisfying.